# Getting Eclipse Working With Libgdx Library

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

**FIXED IT : I needed to rename the StarAssaultActivity.java to MainActivity.java** DOH

I've been following this tutorial: http://obviam.net/index.php/getting-started-in-android-game-development-with-libgdx-create-a-working-prototype-in-a-day-tutorial-part-1/

I've been trying to figure out how to get a working app running on my 4.1.2 Android phone. I've gotten it to run fine on my computer (the tutorial explains this), but when I run it on my phone, it doesn't work. Here is the LogCat log that Eclipse gives me when I try to run it on my phone :

```
12-25 15:42:35.873: E/Trace(7827): error opening trace file: No such file or directory
12-25 15:42:35.873: D/ActivityThread(7827): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
12-25 15:42:35.873: D/ActivityThread(7827): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
12-25 15:42:35.873: D/ActivityThread(7827): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
12-25 15:42:35.923: D/AndroidRuntime(7827): Shutting down VM
12-25 15:42:35.923: W/dalvikvm(7827): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40cb8438)
12-25 15:42:35.923: E/AndroidRuntime(7827): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-25 15:42:35.923: E/AndroidRuntime(7827): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to     instantiate activity     ComponentInfo{net.obviam.starassault/net.obviam.starassault.MainActivity}:     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "net.obviam.starassault.MainActivity"     on path: /data/app/net.obviam.starassault-1.apk
12-25 15:42:35.923: E/AndroidRuntime(7827):     at    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2024)
12-25 15:42:35.923: E/AndroidRuntime(7827):     at   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2132)
12-25 15:42:35.923: E/AndroidRuntime(7827):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
12-25 15:42:35.923: E/AndroidRuntime(7827):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1231)
12-25 15:42:35.923: E/AndroidRuntime(7827):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-25 15:42:35.923: E/AndroidRuntime(7827):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-25 15:42:35.923: E/AndroidRuntime(7827):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
12-25 15:42:35.923: E/AndroidRuntime(7827):     at   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-25 15:42:35.923: E/AndroidRuntime(7827):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-25 15:42:35.923: E/AndroidRuntime(7827):     at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
12-25 15:42:35.923: E/AndroidRuntime(7827):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
12-25 15:42:35.923: E/AndroidRuntime(7827):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-25 15:42:35.923: E/AndroidRuntime(7827): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "net.obviam.starassault.MainActivity"  on path: /data/app/net.obviam.starassault-1.apk
12-25 15:42:35.923: E/AndroidRuntime(7827):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
12-25 15:42:35.923: E/AndroidRuntime(7827):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-25 15:42:35.923: E/AndroidRuntime(7827):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-25 15:42:35.923: E/AndroidRuntime(7827):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
12-25 15:42:35.923: E/AndroidRuntime(7827):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2015)
12-25 15:42:35.923: E/AndroidRuntime(7827):     ... 11 more
12-25 15:42:38.045: I/Process(7827): Sending signal. PID: 7827 SIG: 9
```

My setup in Eclipse is identical to the tutorial linked above, although I should mention I had to make some minor changes to the code to get it to compile. But it works on my computer just fine, so I don't think the problem resides in the core game code.

I've completed the part of the tutorial that has this image : [image]

Here's my workspace, cause why not :

[image]

Ther warning in WorldRenderer.java is because it's saying a library is unused, which, I don't *think* is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Ensure that your MainActivity class inside your android project is in the package 'net.obviam.starassault'.

2) Did you try running android app just after running setup-ui? (before modification) This ensures that platform and settings are ok.

3) You are NOT using JDK 7 right? :D

Hope this helps.

Comment: Fixed it! Easy fix, huzzah. Wasting internet bandwidth with a question I solved myself, not so great.